# update a number automatically

Tags: c#, numbers

Hi i am using C# 2010 Windows Forms application,and for my project i want to know how can i make a variable increment automatically when i add a new member also i excepted when i remove any member the number of reset members will decremented by 1 i hope that i make my problem clear for you and thanks for any help......sorry for my bad english

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AddressBookInC
{
    class Addresses
    {
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String AddressEmail { get; set; }
        public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you add and remove members?

Comment: Where is this variable in code...the one you want to increment/decrement?  And what "member" are you adding/removing?

Comment: I'm using a list so when i pressed add it will add the information to my list

Comment: Why not just use the `List`'s built-in  `Count` property?

Comment: @DonBoitnott AddressID

Comment: @BassamBadr Is this because you want to INSERT into a database at some point?  Are you trying to emulate an IDENTITY style field and name it AddressID?  If not, then Charles Bretana seems to be on the right track...you need a custom Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I know what you want.

You should use `List<Address>` and keep all members in the list.

I assume that AddressID is 1 based.

When adding new member, use number of elements in the list as new AddressID, then add new member to the list.

After removing member or members, sort the list by AddressID and for each member in the list, his new AddressID is his position in the list incremented by one.

Comment: let guess that i add 5 members and i in some point remove member number 3 so is the addressID of member 5 wich is 5 will changed to number 4.....sorry for my bad english bro

Answer (score 1):

Well why don't you place them in a `List<Address>`, something like:

```
List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();

addresses.Add(new Address());
addresses.Add(new Address());

Console.WriteLine(addresses.Count); // now gives you Count of 2

addresses.RemoveAt(0);

Console.WriteLine(addresses.Count); // now gives you Count of 1
```

And here is your `Address` class:

```
class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String AddressEmail { get; set; }
    public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: sorry bro not this what i mean

Comment: let guess that i add 5 members and i in some point remove member number 3 so is the addressID of member 5 wich is 5 will changed to number 4.....sorry for my bad english bro

Comment: So you want to keep a seed ? Sort of like identity for each `Address` ?

Comment: @BassamBadr In this case you could still use the `.Count` to set the AddressID of the last `Address` in the List. It would affect the items if you remove item number 3. The rest have an address set already.

Comment: @BassamBadr It is also much better if you let this be handled by your database or possibly by `EF`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30988/discussion-between-bassam-badr-and-dimitar-dimitrov)

Answer (score 0):

Add Events, with names for example `AddressBookItemAdded` and `AddressBookItemRemoved` to your addressbook and fire them whenever you add/remove any contact. In the eventHandlers of those events just increment/decrement the number of contacts.

check this for example:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Base your `Addresses` collection on one of the built-in collection classes (like `List`) and use it's intrinsic `Count` property.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AddressBookInC
{
    public class Addresses: List<Address> { }
    public class Address
    {
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String AddressEmail { get; set; }
        public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

-- client code somewhere

```
 var myAddresses = new Addresses();
 myAddresses.Add(new Address{AddressId = 1, FirstName= "Bob", etc. });
 myAddresses.Add(new Address{AddressId = 2, FirstName= "Dave", etc. });
 myAddresses.Add(new Address{AddressId = 3, FirstName= "Al", etc. });

 int count = myAddresses.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a class of addresses and you want to count them automatically.

Here is how to do it:

Add a public property named "Count" to your Addresses class.

Add an Event called: NumChanged to the class.

and every time user of class creates a new address or removes an address you should raise that event and set count to count+1 or count-1

Comment: let guess that i add 5 members and i in some point remove member number 3 so is the addressID of member 5 wich is 5 will changed to number 4.....sorry for my bad english bro

Comment: OK. The point is how you add 5 members? You need somesort of collecion or array inside your class to contain these members. One example is you have an array of addresses inside your class. Then you implement an ADD method for your class. Then user of class creates a new instance of Addresses class and using ADD method adds 5 member to that internal array. In this case you can also have a public property called Count which goes up every time you add a member. to be able to remove internal members, instead of an array you should use a collection , for example a List object. Logic is same.

Comment: @S Nash i understand from you talk that is no any ready tool in c# to do this i have to make my own one???

Comment: No there is no tool to do everything for you. You need to write your code. Another suggested answer was to use List<Address>. Even in this case also you need to write more code: 1: Create the Address class 2:Every time user want a new Address, use the Add method of List to add it to the List.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a static variable that increment each time a new class is generated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AddressBookInC
{
    class Addresses
    {
        private static int _incrementId = 0;

        public Addresses()
        {
            AddressID = _incrementId++;
        }

        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String AddressEmail { get; set; }
        public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Sometime it's better to just let the database do it by itself. Have ID 0 for new items until they are inserted in the database.